# vector cropping failure

Tags: qgis

I’m trying to crop a vector contour layer using the instructions given at http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/qgis-user/2012-February/015294.html . I created a polygon in a newly-created vector layer, outlining the area I want to keep. (My polygon layer has the same CLS as the contour layer I want to crop.) However, when I finish I get a shapefile with nothing left in it. All of the contour lines get cropped out, inside the polygon and outside of it.

Any idea what the problem might be?

Comment: Silly question, but did you save the polygon feature in your new vector layer before attempting the clip operation?  If you merely created the polygon and then attempted to clip, you would get the result you mention.

Comment: Great, Mappa. Never estimate my capacity for silliness. THANKS!

By the way, this is a great way to streamline one's data and increase redraw speed, etc..

Comment: Glad to help - we've all done it :)